# finding a correct color

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code works for the first two examples in the docstring, but it doesn't work for the third one. I want the third one to return an empty list, but I'm not sure how to. Can anyone please help me fix this? I want to say return a 'w' if the str values in both lists are the same but in different position and return an empty list if they are in the same position.

```
def find_colour_correct(answer, guess):
'''
(list, list) -> list
```

Given two lists of single character strs return a list of 'w's where the 
number of 'w's is equal to the number of str in the second list that have 
the same value as str in the first list but different position.

```
>>> find_colour_correct(['d', 'c', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f'])
['w', 'w']
>> find_colour_correct(['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'd', 'i'])
['w']
find_colour_correct(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
[]
'''

result = []
for char in guess:
    if char in answer:
        result.append('w')
return result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are just missing the position check:

```
result = []
def find_colour_correct(answer, guess):
    for x in range(len(answer)):
        if answer[x] in guess and answer[x] != guess[x]:
            result.append('w')
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

A double loop might work and shouldn't be an issue if you have a list with few items:

```
def find_colour_correct(answer, guess):
    result = []
    for index, char in enumerate(guess):
        for index2, char2 in enumerate(answer):
            if char == char2 and not index == index2:
                result.append('w')
    return result
```

Or if you like a (probably too long) one-liner:

```
def find_colour_correct(answer, guess):
    return ["w" for i, c in enumerate(guess) for i2, c2 in enumerate(answer) if c == c2 and not i == i2]
```